# Using the date() function I always get the same date, why?

Tags: php, function, variables, date

I always get February 28 2011 using the following date function:

```
$time = $row['time'];
$date = date("F t Y",$time);
```

None of the timestamps were created on the 28th of febuary (obviously) but here is the rest of the code anyway:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `approved`='1' ORDER BY time DESC";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
//Post//

$title = $row['title'];
$content = $row['content'];
$time = $row['time'];
$date = date("F t Y",$time);
$creatorid = $row['uid'];
$creator = username($creatorid);

echo "<div class=\"post\">
        <h1>".$title."</h1>
            <p class=\"entry\">".$content."</p>
            <div class=\"byline\">
                <p class=\"info\">
                Posted ".$date." By ".$creator."
                </p>
                <p class=\"links\"><a href=\"#\">Read More</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"#\">Comments</a></p>
            </div>
    </div>";
}
```

Thanks
Cameron

Comment: What does the "time" field contains ? MySQL timestamp, integer ?

Comment: Have you looked at the values stored in the database ?  What are they ?

Comment: I think they are unix time stamps, is that what they are called? They were generated using the time() function

Comment: I think simply date("F t Y") would suffice.  You cant mix datestamps in formatted date calls

Comment: Yeah, time() returns a unix time stamp. If you're storing that timestamp in mysql directly in an `int` field, then you can also use mysql do the date conversion for you: `date_format(from_unixtime(time), '%M %j %Y'))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
$date = date("F t Y",$time);
```

this gives the output:
   "Name of the month" "Number of days in that month (In february, it is 28 whereas in January, it is 31" and "Year".

You should change it with:

```
$date = date("F j Y",$time);
```

OR

```
$date = date("F d Y",$time);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: you just beat me to it  "t is indeed the number of days in that month so for February it's 28".

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of `$row['time']`? There's a good chance that it's not a time value that PHP supports but is instead a `datetime` MYSQL type.

Instead use:

```
$time = strtotime($row['time']);
```